# Return specific list, from list of lists, using for loop

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I want to use a for loop to find a list, within a list of lists.

Why does it return list 0 instead of list 2?

```
def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):
    """ (list of list of str, int) -> str

    Return the characters from the row of the board with index row_index
    as a single string.

    >>> make_str_from_row([['H', 'O', 'U', 'S', 'E'], ['B', 'E', 'D'], ['C', 'H', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'E']], 2)
    'CHEESE'
    """

    letter = ''
    line = ''

    for row_index in board:
        for letter in row_index:
            line = line + letter
        return line

make_str_from_row([['H', 'O', 'U', 'S', 'E'], ['B', 'E', 'D'], ['C', 'H', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'E']], 2)
```

Comment: Get rid of your outer loop. Do `for letter in board[row_index]:` for your inner loop.  Or get rid of all loops and just `return ''.join(board[row_index])`.

Comment: Thanks @StevenRumbalski  Very clear, concise explaination!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row_index` is not what you think it is. In Python, the for loop syntax you're using causes the control variable to store the element in a collection (in this context). In other words, you're iterating through each sub-list in `board`, where for each iteration,`row_index` is updated to point to the next sub-list.
What you need is a single access and then your inner for loop:

```
sub_list = board[row_index]
    for letter in sub_list:
        line = line + letter
    return line
```

The following is equivalent:

```
    for letter in board[row_index]:
        line = line + letter
    return line
```

On another note, since your function is meant to return a concatenated String version of a given sub_list, you may consider the one-line solution...

`return ''.join(board[row_index])`

...to concatenate the characters in the string at `board[row_index]`.
`join` is considered more efficient than `+=` because it avoids the wasteful constructing and discarding of sub-strings. (You create a completely different String for each `+=`.) Especially for long Strings, `join` is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks @synchronizer! I'm a little confused about one thing. Why does the function return the sub-list[0]. If the function is iterating though every sub-list, why does it not return all the sub-lists? Thanks!

Comment: @sim You're welcome. To answer your question, the function retruns only sub-list 0 as a String because you return pre-maturely within your loop. That is, you return at the end of the first iteration before the loop has a chance to append the characters from the rest of the `sub_lists`. (That's the undesired behavior though). Does that help?

Comment: That's awesome! Headache removed! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are always returning the first element of the list. Keep in mind that `return` makes the function to immediately finish. In addition, your variable `letter` could be removed. You do not need to initialize it since it is part of your for loop. Finally, your code could be simply:

```
def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):
    """ (list of list of str, int) -> str

    Return the characters from the row of the board with index row_index
    as a single string.

    >>> make_str_from_row([['H', 'O', 'U', 'S', 'E'], ['B', 'E', 'D'], ['C', 'H', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'E']], 2)
    'CHEESE'
    """

    return ''.join(board[row_index])
```